# Sending data to AWS RDS using mysqlimport " mysqlimport: Error: 1045 Access denied for user 'admin'@'xxxx' (using password: YES "

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, mysqlimport

I want to import data that is in a text file on my local machine to my AWS RDS database instance. I have configured my options file `my.cnf` with the required parameters that is `hostname`, `port`,`password` and `user name`.

This is the mysql import command that I run at the terminal:

```
mysqlimport --local covid patient.txt
```

I have set my aws RDS instance to be pubicly accessible
But I am getting the error below

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1045 Access denied for user 'admin'@'1xx.xxx.xx.x' (using password: YES
```

I know there is something I am not doing right. Help me with any troubleshooting options

UPDATE AFTER TRYING OUT SEVERAL OPTIONS ON THE INTERNET

My security group inbound rules are set to allow tracffic from any IP.

When I run the command for `mysqlimport` I am now getting a new error.
here is what I get.

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

Now I know I am supposed to `GRANT` privileges for the user. Problemm is I don't know how to.
I got some advice from the internet and tried it like so.

I tried to

```
 GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '#######' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but I get an error like this

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'specialQ123#' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1
```

I have also tried to create a new user then try to grant all privileges. In this case the SQL executes but I still can't use the `mysqlimport` utility.

It still throws me this error

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

I might be asking something very simple but it's really frustrating me.
SOMEONE PLEASE SAVE ME

Comment: did you confirm that you can access your db with telnet ?

Comment: I can access my DB through the shell using mysql command by specifying the host and username plus password

Comment: you cant grant super, system priv via aws. i am still trying to find a solution for this myself